# Kde. Set plasma 5.0 lockscreen

Tags: kubuntu, kde, lock-screen, plasma

I want to set plasma 5.0 lockscreen.

http://www.kde.org/announcements/plasma5.0/screenshots/lockscreen.png

When I execute

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure kdm
```

I see list with gdm, kdm, lightdm. There is not lock screen of plasma 5.0 although it installed and I can launch it from kdm.

Answer (score 1):

You need Plasma 5 on your system. There are three ways to get this with Kubuntu.

1. The Project Neon 5 PPA offers frequently updated development snapshots of KDE Frameworks and Plasma. Packages will be installed to `/opt/project-neon5` and will co-install on your Trusty 14.04 (but not earlier) system.

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:neon/kf5
   apt update
   apt install project-neon5-session project-neon5-utils project-neon5-konsole
   ```

   Log out and in again.
2. Releases of KDE Frameworks 5 and Plasma 5 are being packaged in the Kubuntu **next** PPA. These will *replace* your Frameworks 4 / Plasma 4 install and requires a working Utopic 14.10 system.

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/next
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ci-train-ppa-service/landing-005
   apt update
   apt install kubuntu-plasma5-desktop
   apt full-upgrade
   ```

   Log out and in again.
3. The [Neon 5 live image](http://files.kde.org/snapshots/), updated every Friday with latest source from Git to run a full system from a USB disk.

([source](https://blogs.kde.org/2014/07/15/plasma-5-here-all-ready-eat-your-babies))

Comment: I want to change **lock screen**. I have already done above. And I can run plasma 5.0 from kdm. I want to replace kdm to plasma 5.0 lock screen.